# Why does PHP response to AJAX contains <script> aBunchOfJavascriptHere </script>?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure this out from 2 hours with no luck, maybe it's not that technical but I need help!

I've an AJAX script that needs to send a GET request to a php script that's on the same page.
The PHP script terminates like this

```
      if ($success) {
        print( $state );
      }?>
```

The Javascript is rightly under the php termination and is this.

```
<script>
  $('table button').click( function() {
    var button = $(this);
    /* if button inside the table is clicked */
    var username = button.parent().parent().children('td').html();
    var state = button.html();

    /* send GET request */
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'index.php',
      data: 'username='+username+'&state='+state,
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

What I don't understand is why I get the alert containing this text

```
inside // this is the state, so it's good
<script> // this is the script, not good
  $('table button').click( function() {
    var button = $(this);
    /* if button inside the table is clicked */
    var username = button.parent().parent().children('td').html();
    var state = button.html();

    /* send GET request */
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'index.php',
      data: 'username='+username+'&state='+state,
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I've to manipulate the HTML on success by I'm not able to do that because of the messy response that I get from my php code. I'm not sure if I've to post other code. If you need to know more just ask, I'll reply as soon as possible.

Comment: are you relying on `register_globals` or have you got some code to set `$state` to `$_GET['state']` in the PHP? (you should be doing the latter). Also, it's better to use `data:{'username':username,'state':state}` in jQuery's `ajax` function, because you can change the form type and it will adjust.

Comment: +1 for the {'username':username,'state':state} advice

Answer (score 4):

Any characters outside `<?php ?>` tags are sent back in the response. That's how you get that `<script>` tag in the first place when you access index.php from the browser.

echo and print are obviously going to also send data.

So I guess you should have that `if($success)` at the begining of index.php and `exit;` inside it, after `print`.

Characters outside `<?php ?>` tags are sent as part of the response for historical and practical reasons.
In our days having PHP code mixed with HTML is a bad practice (as some people already pointed out in the comments bellow). You either use a templating engine (most people know about Smarty) or use PHP itself as a templating engine.
But "back in the day" PHP started out as *just* a simple templating engine (no classes, external modules, namespaces, autoloaders, etc.), so mixing HTML with PHP was basically the purpose of this language.
As I said, today we still use PHP as a templating language so mixing PHP (control structures, loops) and HTML works.

Comment: +1 because it works! I'd make this the accepted answer if you would be more specific on why the things outside the php tags are sent back in the response (that's what the question is about after all), thank you anyway :)

Comment: @domenicop that's just how PHP works. When it was first invented, it was intended to do small tasks within a page (like display a hit-counter), so everything outside the tags is sent to the client as if you'd `print`ed them, as a convenience. That's also why it has html-looking opening and closing tags; `<div><?php print $hitcount ?></div>`. These days, the way it's used has evolved to be quite different, but the old behaviour remains, and some people still use it (personally I think it makes for very ugly code though).

Answer (score 2):

A quick, but not recommended fix is to avoid the javascript content on an ajax request

Just demonstrating, how it could be,

```
if($success) {
    print( $state );
  }

if(!isset($_GET['ajax_call']))
{ ?>
  <script>
  $('table button').click( function() {
  var button = $(this);
  /* if button inside the table is clicked */
  var username = button.parent().parent().children('td').html();
  var state = button.html();

/* send GET request */
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'index.php?ajax_call=1',
  data: 'username='+username+'&state='+state,
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
});
  </script>
<?php
}?>
```

.....

and you should note that the new ajax call has an additional variable, ajax_call,

This is a quick fix, for you to move on, but i suggest you to use an MVC framework.

Comment: when you say MVC do you mean I should put the javascript in a 'js' folder and 'require' it via php? I know what's the MVC paradigm in general, just want to be sure what it become when why talk about web development

Comment: In general it means the same, i.e to separate the code and design to avoid the mess, but what i meant is to use a framework like codeignitor.